# Linear Algebra - independent vectors or not

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the vectors $(1,1,1,0),(0,-1,-1,1),(1,0,-1,1),(1,0,-2,1)\in \mathbb{R}^4$ are linearly independent and they can be used as a base for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

How I solved this?

Well, first I let $$x(1,1,1,0) + y(0,-1,-1,1) + z(1,0,-1,1) + c(1,0,-2,1)  = (0,0,0,0).$$

So, it's about solving equations system following:

\begin{align}
x+z+c&=0\\
x-y&=0 \\
x-y-z-2c&=0\\
 y+z+c&=0
\end{align}

Then, I got $x = 1 , y = 1 , z = -2$ and $c = 1$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that means that they are linearly dependent. Notice that any common scalar multiple of $x, y, z$ and $c$ will also give a linear dependence relation among the vectors. Do you now know whether they can be used as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: they cant be used as a basis for R^4 because they are linearly dependent, but please can you confirm if x = 1 , y = 1 , z = -2 and c = 1 got correct numbers ? thank you.

Comment: Indeed, because $x,y,z, c \neq 0$ you know that they are not linearly independent. The answer $x = 1 , y = 1 , z = -2$ and $c = 1$ is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what BRIC-Fan said the reason this work is because when you have the sets (1,1,1,0),(0,−1,−1,1),(1,0,−1,1),(1,0,−2,1) $\in R^4$ to know its linearly indepedent you need to get a linearly to show that the only solution to the given equation a(1,1,1,0) + b(0,-1,-1,1) + c(1,0,-1,1) + d(1,0,-2,1) = 0 is the trivial solution i.e that a = b = c = d = 0;

This corresponds to 4 equations with 4 unknowns 
a + c + d = 0
a - b = 0
a - b - c -2d = 0
b + c + d = 0

So putting this into matrix form we get

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

times the coefficient matrix and that is equal to 0, so to show it has solution it must be invertible so that is why you need to calculate the determinant!

Comment: or another way is just do row-reduced echelon form and you either get the 4x4 identity hence the only solution for the coefficients are 0 or if its Linearly dependent you will find it won't row reduce to the 4x4 identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: calculate $\text{ det }\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and if its $0$, then they are dependent, if not they are independent.

Comment: Does i need to use gaussian elimination here or i calculate like this 1+0+1+1 = 3 and so on?